# Getting current position of PyAudio stream?

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, pyaudio

I'm currently working on a project which involves processing an audio file using FFMpeg, and then pipelining this into a PyAudio instance.

I cannot see anywhere in the documentation on how to retrieve the current position of the audio stream. I'm writing to the PyAudio instance in chunks of (44100 * 2).

Does this imply that 1 second of audio, would correspond to 1 of these chunks, or am I mistaken?

Comment: If your feed from ffmpeg is 16-bit 44100 Hz mono, then 88200 bytes is 1 second of samples.

Comment: That makes complete sense, thank-you! So, would stereo therefore be 88200 x 2, and hence 176400 bytes?

Comment: Yes. ..,........,